# Adobe folder level JS runs on Acrobat Pro DC but not allowed on Acrobat Reader DC

Tags: adobe-reader, fdf, adobe-javascript

I have an use case where PDF form is downloaded from IIS / MVC, filled by end user and submitted back to server. After successful submit FDF response triggers document protection to disallow changes to document. Protection is activated by folder level javascript function:

```
function applySecurity()
{
var DoApplyMySecurity = app.trustedFunction( function(){
var oMyPolicy = null;
app.beginPriv();
// First, Get the ID of My Security Policy
var aPols = security.getSecurityPolicies()
for(var index=0;index<aPols.length;index++){
    if(aPols[index].name == "AgreementPolicy"){
        oMyPolicy = aPols[index]; break;
    }
}
if(oMyPolicy == null){ app.alert("Policy Not Found"); return; }
   // Now, Apply the security Policy
   var rtn = this.encryptUsingPolicy({oPolicy: oMyPolicy });
if(rtn.errorCode != 0) app.alert("Security Error: " + rtn.errorText); 
   app.endPriv();
});
DoApplyMySecurity();
}
```

Document level function calls the above function as follows:

```
function valuesSaved(msg)
{
   app.alert(msg);
   applySecurity();
   app.execMenuItem("Save");
   app.execMenuItem("Close");
}
```

The problem is that when submitting the form using Acrobat Reader DC the following error occurs:

> NotAllowedError: Security settings prevent access to this property or method.
>   Security.getSecurityPolicies:7:Doc undefined:Exec

When using Acrobat Pro DC security is applied successfully.
I have exported security settings from Pro DC to Reader DC.
What I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the intention - Reader verion cannot by default save changed PDF